# Parse CSV and seperate fields with multiple values

Tags: python, csv

CSV has field that is being parsed which may or may not have entries within the field that have values that are additionally separated by comma.

```
import csv

def import_text(filename, separator):
    for line in csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=separator,
                           skipinitialspace=True):
        if line[19]:
           for elt in line[19].split(','):
               yield elt


for data in import_text('filename.csv', ','):
    print (data)
```

Using the script above, column 20 in a CSV will print the following:

```
a
b, c, d
e, f
```

I would instead like b, c, d; e, f to print on their own respective lines like so:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: You might have to be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps you're looking for `for elt in line[19].split(','):` around your yield statement

Comment: Trying to expand the values that are comma separated within a field. Tried your response but get the same results, see updated question.

Comment: Could you post a short, but realistic example of your input and (desired) output? The abc snippet isn't helpful at all.

Comment: Something to think about: `for elt in line[19].split(','):` is redundant if you never use `elt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the column and yield fields individually:

```
import csv

def import_text(filename, separator):
  for line in csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=separator, skipinitialspace=True):
    if line[19]:
      for elt in line[19].split(separator):
        yield elt.strip()

for data in import_text('filename.csv', ','):
  print (data)
```

Comment: I am not clear where `c.split` might fall in my example code.

Comment: after modifying your answer it wouldn't. I'll edit to include the complete solution. The only difference is that the previous snippet could fit without modification, whereas this modifies your code to work.

Comment: That works though there is a space prefixing the lines that were split. How would you prevent the space from printing?

Comment: use the python string `strip()` method. Amended answer to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

def import_text(filename, separator):
    for line in csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=separator, skipinitialspace=True):
        if len(line) > 19:
            for elt in line[19].split(separator):
                yield elt

for data in import_text('filename.csv', ','):
    print (data)
```